# Wordpress website is opening too Slow

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

My WordPress website is opening too slow,
After adding the wp job manager plugin Website running slowly. I have installed W3 super cache and wordpress cdn enabler plugins. When i test my site in pingdom    http://www.web.com/jm-ajax/get_listings file to take nearly 40 seconds to load. Please help me why the site running slowly.

Comment: You're not really providing a lot of information to go on here... define "slowly" how long is it taking? Is this browser specific? What version are you using?

Comment: am using wp job manager Version 1.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this htaccess booster to very top of your .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/vYwAp8bg

Answer (score 0):

To clarify why your website loads too slowly, you could open the delevoper console in your browser and check the network activity. Just open the network panel and hit reload (F5).

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that can influence your Wordpress site's loading time. Therefore we would need more information as to what the problem is or a link to your site / a site speed test in order to give you clearer direction.

However to get you started I would recommend taking a read through a [Wordpress Speed up Guide](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-up-wordpress/) to see if you can improve upon any of the suggestions mentioned.